# How long does it take to enable the custom questions list?

Tags: support, custom-questions-list

Some weeks ago I enabled the Custom Questions List feature in my profile.

I note the feature description states

> We are gradually enabling this feature to users who opt in. You may
>   not see changes reflected immediately.

I understand from related Meta posts [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/397555), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317675/custom-question-lists-october-status-update#comment1041949_317675) that enrollment is not automatic and may not be immediate.  Any idea how long it might take before I see the feature?

Comment: Can the downvoters suggest how this question can be improved (at the time of writing +2/-4)? It's crystal clear, generally applicable, and asked in good faith as a support (rather than feature) request.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this feature started appearing for me on 7 May (2019).

Answer (score 2):

### You might simply not get that test feature enabled.

Joe mentioned in his [introductory post to the Alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/363946) that they "are limiting the number of people who have access." That means there is no guarantee that everyone who clicks that button will be given access.

Considering that they started testing back in August, they may be at a stage right now where they just don't need any new testers.

At the bottom of that question, it looks like they were hoping for the official release to be ready in January, but that's already come and gone and the feature hasn't been implemented yet. If we're lucky, the feature will be enabled for everyone shortly, or it could take another 6 to 8 weeks.